# How to iterate to define dataframes and them export them like a csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am choosing rows containing days of the week and saving them 1 by 1:

```
Monday_df = df.loc[df['day_of_week'] == 'Monday']
Tuesday_df = df.loc[df['day_of_week'] == 'Tuesday']
...
Sunday_df = df.loc[df['day_of_week'] == 'Sunday']
```

Then exporting them 1 by 1:

```
Monday_df.to_csv('Monday.csv',index=False)
Tuesday_df.to_csv('Tuesday.csv',index=False)
...
Sunday_df.to_csv('Sunday.csv',index=False)
```

Question:

Can I do these 14 steps (define days(7) and then export days(7)) in 2 steps with a loop or smth else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for day in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']:
    day_df = df.loc[df['day_of_week'] == day]
    day_df.to_csv(f'{day}.csv', index=False)
```

This will loop over list of the days of the week. For each one it creates the subset dataframe for that particular day than writes it out to file.

I am using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) here to dynamically create the output csv name. So the solution requires at least python 3.6 to work. You could use `.format` or the super old and annoying format with percent signs and what not.